# How to remove personal information from .FBX files

Tags: export, .fbx, path

I recently noticed that if you export to FBX then open the .FBX file in Notepad and search for ".blend" you can see the original .blend file name and full path.

So my question is it's possible to remove this kind of personal information because I would like to sell the 3d models on different stores?